# actix-web uses redis connection pool

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am using [redis](https://crates.io/crates/redis) in `actix-web 4`

```
actix-web = "4"
redis = { version = "0.21", features = ["r2d2", "cluster", "connection-manager", "tokio-comp", "tokio-native-tls-comp"] }
```

I created redis client in main

```rs
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1:6379/").expect("err");
    let serve = HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(redis_client.clone()))
    });
}
```

Then get this redis client in the route

```rs
pub async fn list(
    query: web::Query<ListRequest>,
    redis_client: web::Data<redis::Client>,
) -> HttpResult {
    let mut con = redis_client.get_tokio_connection().await.map_err(hje)?;
    let _: () = con.set("my_key", 42).await.map_err(hje)?;
}
```

The above code works fine, but I would like to know how to use r2d2 to create a pool of redis connections instead of a single connection

I found in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/redis/0.21.5/redis/#optional-features) that r2d2 can be supported, but I don't know how to use it, can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

The `"r2d2"` feature will implement [`r2d2::ManageConnection`](https://docs.rs/r2d2/latest/r2d2/trait.ManageConnection.html) for [`redis::Client`](https://docs.rs/redis/0.21.5/redis/struct.Client.html) meaning you can create a pool like so:

```
r2d2::Pool::new(redis_client).unwrap();
```

Comment: How to get an asynchronous connection from the pool? When I get it like this, I get the error `let mut con = redis_pool.get_tokio_connection().await.map_err(hje)?;` `method not found in actix_web::web::Data<Pool<Client>>`

Comment: As far as I know, r2d2 does not support creating new connections asynchronously so it'd only provide the synchronous connections.

Comment: If it is synchronous, does it mean that I have to run the operations on redis in `actix_web::web::block`